# Glitch about flags?

Tags: bug, flags

Yesterday, while I was trying to flag a post the flag glitched and I wasn't able to flag it. Today, however the flag button returned to normal. What was going on?

Comment: What do you mean "the flag glitched"? Did you get some kind of error message? It's likely that this was just a temporary issue

Comment: Yes, I did get one. It said "flag is not available"

Comment: Hmm... Do you know what post you were trying to flag and what kind of flag you were trying to cast? Some flags become invalid when a post gets deleted, so it's possible that the post was already gone when you tried to flag

Comment: As @Unionhawk was getting into, next time that happens refresh (`CTRL` + `R` in most browsers) and see what happens. If the post has disappeared, than that is the issue and it was just deleted between the time you flagged and loaded the page.